# Cath throwed notice 'relation already exists' from dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I need create table dinamically, after this, I need create also index on this table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func() RETURNS void 
as
$$
begin
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(field  int)';

EXECUTE 'create unique index index_name on t(field)';

EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO t(field) values(1)';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

When table does not exists, this function works, created table an index also, but when table and index already exists, there are throwed notice: `relation "t" already exists` and error: `relation "index_name" already exists`.

So, I need catch exception from first query and do not create index, if catched notice: `table already exists`

That is, how to do somethng like this ?

```
begin
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(field  int)';
```

**`IF HERE NOT CATCHED NOTICE  'relation "t" already exists'  THEN`**

**`EXECUTE 'create unique index index_name on t(field)';`**

**`END IF;`**

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO t(field) values(1)';
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an exception block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func() 
RETURNS void as $$
begin
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(field  int)';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'create unique index index_name on t(field)';
    EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
        -- do nothing
    END;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO t(field) values(1)';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Read: [Control Structures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).